# Maximum MYSQL_ERRNO Allowed

Tags: mysql

I use "custom errors" in my stored functions in MySQL if specific requirements are not met and are important enough to "stop the show".

The custom error routine assigns an error number to MYQL_ERRNO and description that my PHP code then reads and processes accordingly.

I know there is an upper limit to the MYSQL_ERRNO, during testing of a function I deliberately threw an error but got an out of range back for MYQL_ERRNO.

Does anyone know what the upper and lower limits for the MYSQL_ERRNO are? Any help or insight would be most helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MYSQL_ERRNO is defined as an unsigned Small Int [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) so I guess 0 to 65535

Comment: Many thanks, that was my problem. Appreciate the quick answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment made by RiggsFolly was exactly what I was searching for. I was trying to assign an error number of 90001 and thus the problem.

Thanks!